# Enter/update/exit on two-levels, without nesting

Tags: d3.js

To perform enter/update/exit actions on the corresponding sets, we can write the following code, paraphrased from an example by [Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

Here each number appears in a `p` node.

```js
function update(data) {
  var text = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('p')
    .data(data);

  text.enter()
    .append('p')
    .merge(text)
    .text(d => d);

  text.exit().remove();
}
update([1, 2]);
update([3, 4, 5, 6]);
update([7, 8, 9]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now suppose that we want each `p` node to be itself inside a `div` node. This ought to be a simple extension since we need no nesting. But the following obvious modification is flawed.

```js
function update(data) {
  var text = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  text.enter()
    .append('div')
    .append('p')
    .text(d => d)
    .merge(text);

  text.exit()
    .remove();
}
update([1, 2]);
update([3, 4, 5, 6]);
update([7, 8, 9]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Why?

Comment: It doesn't assume you want the `p` tags updated. You have to run them through an update pattern too. I'd say it's similar to a grouped bar chart example where you update the group first and update the bars second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your update selection refers to `<div>` elements, not to `<p>` elements, remove the `merge()` method. Of course, this has the undesired effect of requiring duplicate code (specifically `.text(d => d)`):

```
text.enter()
    .append('div')
    .append('p')
    .text(d => d);

text.select('p')
    .text(d => d);
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
function update(data) {
  var text = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  text.enter()
    .append('div')
    .append('p')
    .text(d => d);

  text.select('p')
    .text(d => d);

  text.exit()
    .remove();
}
update([1, 2]);
setTimeout(function() {
  update([3, 4, 5, 6])
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  update([7, 8, 9])
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Another approach, admittedly awkward, is creating a simple selection of divs and using `html` to append the paragraphs with the values:

```
text.enter()
    .append('div')
    .merge(text)
    .html(d => '<p>'+ d + '</p>');
```

Pay attention to the fact that you have to set the values **after** `merge`, just like in your first snippet.

Here is the running code:

```js
function update(data) {
  var text = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  text.enter()
    .append('div')
    .merge(text)
    .html(d => '<p>' + d + '</p>');

  text.exit()
    .remove();
}

update([1, 2]);
setTimeout(function() {
  update([3, 4, 5, 6])
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  update([7, 8, 9])
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, regarding your question:

> Why?

Your second snippet *kind of* works, if you move the `text` to after the `merge`:

```js
function update(data) {
  var text = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  text.enter()
    .append('div')
    .append('p')
    .merge(text)
    .text(d => d);

  text.exit()
    .remove();
}
update([1, 2]);
setTimeout(function() {
  update([3, 4, 5, 6])
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  update([7, 8, 9])
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, as you can see, it's removing the inner `<p>` elements in the updates. That happens because your update selection is a selection of divs, so when you use `text` (which internally uses `textContent`) you're actually removing everything previously appended to those divs.

---

PS: in both S.O. snippets, make sure that `show console` is not checked, otherwise the code will select it as a `<div>` (S.O. snippet uses a `<div>` to show the console).